# Having trouble with javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder build

Tags: java, web-applications, java-7, java-ee-7

My rest api should accept a String relative uri and then redirect to that location.

Therefore, let's say I pass redirect_uri=/login?foo=bar I should redirect to {host}{redirect_uri}.

I'm trying to use UriBuilder , but query parameters are ALWAYS encoded:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("//{baseurl}")
                .path(redirectUri)
                .scheme("https")
                .buildFromEncoded(domainInfo.getHost())
```

result end always with:

```
/login%3Ffoo=bar
```

and successive redirect won't work

```
return Response
            .status(Response.Status.FOUND)
            .location(uri) // uri.toString() should return {baseurl}/login?foo=bar instead!
            .build();
```

Any hints?

Comment: `/login?foo=bar` is not a path.  It’s a path and query, but you are passing it as a path.

Answer (score 0):

`.path(redirectUri)` means that you are passing a path.  That method does not expect a query.  So, `/login?foo=bar` is being treated as a path with no query.

Pass the path portion as a path, and pass the query portion as a query:

```
UriBuilder.fromUri("//{baseurl}")
                .path("/login")
                .queryParam("foo", "bar")
                .scheme("https")
                .buildFromEncoded(domainInfo.getHost())
```

Comment: Sorry, but the snippet above did not answer my question, because location?foo=bar is passed entirily by queryparam

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @VGR comment, I solved with this

```
 UriBuilder.fromUri("//{baseurl}")
                .uri(postLogin) // in place of path
                .scheme("https")
                .buildFromEncoded(domainInfo.getHost())
```